# Using formatting to display a score in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

so i'm trying to display a score in my game when the player picks up a coin, the score is added by 1:

`main.py`

```
scorefont=pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Pixeltype.ttf',50)
score=scorefont.render('Score: {}'.format(level.score),False,'White')
game_active=True
while game_active:
     screen.blit(score,(0,0))
```

`level.py`

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self,level_data,surface):
        self.display_surface=surface
        self.level_building(level_data)
        self.world_shift=0
        self.score=0


playercoin=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.coins,self.player,True,False)
        if len(playercoin)==1:
            self.score+=1
```

However, the score does not get updated in the actual game. I've debugged it, and found out the score is being updated, but the display isn't updated. Where did i go wrong in my code? (All variables are defined, i just didn't show me defining them)

(score is supposed to be 1)

[image]

value of the score variable

[image]

Comment: There is no way to tell what the issue is based off of the limited code you have shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered surface does not magically change when you change the score. The rendered surface and the score are not tied. You need to render the `score` surface again with the new score when the score changes:

```py
playercoin=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.coins,self.player,True,False)
if len(playercoin)==1:
    global score
    self.score+=1
    score=scorefont.render('Score: {}'.format(self.score),False,'White')
```